# How do I restore Windows 8 on an Ultrabook from the system recovery partition?

Tags: windows-8, ultrabook, recovery-partition

I've got a Sony Ultrabook that has a bunch of rescue partitions. One of them is around 15 GB and I am very sure it contains a Windows DVD. The main Windows partition (`C:`) was formatted and I can boot into the recovery thing. When I select to recover, it asks for a CD, which I do not have.

How can I tell it to use the partition instead?

I do not have another Win 8 device to create another medium, like a USB key.

Comment: There should be instructions on HP's website.  You normally pressed a certain button before windows loads.  More info on the problem your trying solve might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access BIO and switch boot menu from CD-Rom to HDD drive or a like...Turn the Laptop off. Once it is off, press the Assist button. This will turn it on and bring up a Menu where you can select to enter the BIOS or boot from other media etc. For more info visit Sony site